# Why the kie-Server cannot be deployed to EAP?

Tags: jboss, drools, kie-server

Kie-Server is an important component of Drools 6.3.0.Last week I meet problem when I try to install kie-Workbench on tomcat, and I finally change platform to JBoss EAP to solve it.But now I meet a new problem when I install kie-Server on EAP.
When I deploy the war packages, the EAP return failure massage to me and I find no solution on Drools document, the failure message as follows:

```
Failed to enable kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee6.war.
Unexpected HTTP response: 500
Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee6.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}
Response
Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: 失败的服务" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee6.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee6.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: 处理 PARSE 的 deployment \"kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee6.war\" 阶段失败`
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}},
   "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Comment: What standalone or domain profile are you using? Try with `standalone.[sh,bat] -c standalone-full.xml`

Comment: the kie-server in the BRMS zip on EAP should definitely work, because it's heavily QA'ed. Maybe the versions don't match. As you seem to got a BRMS/EAP subscription, might be easiest to just [ask support](https://access.redhat.com/).